# NETLOGO: How do I make a turtle die if there are two turtles on one patch?

Tags: netlogo

What I'm trying to figure out is how to make one turtle die when there are two turtles on any one patch.

This is what I've been attempting so far:

```
to deathbytubes
  if ask patches [show count turtles-here] >= 2
  [die]
end
```

How can I fix this so that it works?

Also, can anyone help me figure out how to make turtle die when it comes into contact with another turtle as an alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to kill turtles when they touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926964/how-to-kill-turtles-when-they-touch)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926964/how-to-kill-turtles-when-they-touch covers this pretty well. that said    ask patches with [count turtles- here >= 2][ask turtles-here [die]]  does exactly what you want.

Comment: @mattsap provides a correct answer to your question.  However the question remains: how did you end up with this need?  If you are just trying to enforce a unshared-location constraint, it is better not to put 2 turtles on the same patch in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

This will kill all turtles if there's more than 2 on a patch.

```
ask turtles with [count turtles-here >= 2] [ die]
```

This will kill only 1 turtle if there's only 2 turtles on a patch.

```
ask patches with [count turtles-here = 2] [ ask one-of turtles-here[die]]
```

If there's more than 2 turtles, the following will work. Basically, you figure out which patches have more than 2 turtles and ask one of the turtle's to kill everyone else so that only 1 turtle remains.

```
ask patches with [count turtles-here >= 2] [ ask one-of turtles-here [ ask other turtles-here[die]]]
```

Comment: This can be shortened to simply `ask turtles with [count turtles-here > 2] [ die ]`

Comment: I've updated my solution; however, I think what was previously here and the one in your comment may be incorrect. The question asks for only one turtle to exist on a patch, where as those will kill all turtles if there's more than 1